# Javascript setInterval: first interval is abrupt

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, fadein

When using JavaScript's setInterval method in the example below with jQuery effects, the **initial** display does not appear to engage the fadeIn method. "text" is displayed suddenly.

Subsequent iterations through the chain of effects starting with fadeIn() execute as expected. It is just the first pass where the "text" is displayed suddenly without the fadeIn effect.

Any ideas as to why this occurs?
Thanks - a JavaScript beginner.

```
setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
function myFunction() {
    $('#myId').fadeIn(1500).html("text").delay(2750).fadeOut(1500).delay(1000;
};
```

Comment: what is the initial [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) of the element? if its not already, set the objects `display` style to `none` or `visibility` to `hidden` if you want to keep the space allocated for the element in the DOM.

Comment: Good observation, my element's styling did not address the **display** attribute. Setting it to **none** addressed my concern. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be Fading In without you noticing as the text is added after the fade In. Switch it around, add the text before fading it in. 
Make sure it was not displayed beforehand (in CSS or however you need it).

```
$('#myId').html("text").fadeIn(1500).delay(2750).fadeOut(1500).delay(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing the order, as suggested, does not correct the issue unfortunately.

Comment: is your div hidden in the first place? what css is used on it?

Comment: That was it, I did not address that **display** attribute for the element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is initially blank and hidden, you are fading in an empty element and then setting the text to `text` only after the element is faded in. Reverse those steps:

```
$('#myId').html("text").fadeIn(1500).delay(2750).fadeOut(1500).delay(1000);
```

```js
setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
function myFunction() {
    $('#myId').html("text").fadeIn(1500).delay(2750).fadeOut(1500).delay(1000);
};
```

```css
#myId { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for offering that code as it shed light on my mistake, the issue did lay in that my element's **display** attribute was not set to **none**. Now to understand the lesson.